# Approach for saving data possibly without db

Tags: android, audio, save, storage

I'm working on a school project where I need to continously send small audio data packets to server, once every 10ms or so.

If there is no internet connection, I want to save these bytes somewhere on the phone along with their IDs (they need to be sent in order they were recorded). Once the internet connection is restored, this data is sent to server and upon being accepted by server they can be removed.

I thought of simply saving this into some JSON or txt file but then, wouldn't there be a better solution?

Comment: https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB ?

Comment: @pksink She asked for approach without using db

Comment: ok, i must be blind ;-) - i just read the question body, not the title...